# Disclaimer boilerplate at the end of documents

Tags: docusignapi

In our Docusign process - using the REST API - we have one company but two organization names, call them Org A and Org B. Org B uses the API with the authoritative copy flag = 1, so at the end of the packets they're printing, a "Certificate of Completion" and two pages of legal boilerplate are appended to the envelope. Org A doesn't use the flag, their documents don't get the certificate and boilerplate.

Question #1: The certificate and boilerplate are not in the document Org B is sending for signature, so can I assume that's part of the authoritative copy process?

The legal boilerplate has the parent company's name - and my email - throughout the text. Org B would like their own information in that space.

Question #2: They have their own credentials on the Docusign account, so is that sort of customization possible?

Answer (score 1):

So, there are two things you are refering to here and there's some confusion.

1. [Certificate of Completion](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=oeq1643226594604&topicId=gpa1578456339545.html&_LANG=enus). This one is generated by DocuSign for every transaction (every envelope). It doesn't have to be visible or downloaded by customers, but it's always there. If you ask for it in your code, you get it. This is not a document to be signed or be acted on. It's just a summary of everything that happened and it's used for legal purposes.
2. The second thing you refer to as "boilerplate" is called the [Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=aqg1583277336549.html&_LANG=enus) and is something that recipients have to agree to once and forever (unless they retract or change their information like email or name). This one is controlled by DocuSign, if DocuSign determine you are a new signer that didn't yet consent to the ERSD - then you're asked to do so. As a developer you have no control over this process.

Comment: And to add on to Inbar's answer, the download of the CoC as part of the envelope documents has nothing to do with Authoritative Copy.  You specify in the document request whether or not you want the CoC (with appended Disclosure) included in the returned documents, whether the returned documents are requested as individual (archive) or as combined in a single contiguous PDF.

Comment: If I'm following this correctly: there is no way to have Org B's information on the Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure instead of the parent company's? They're using their own credentials to send.

Comment: The ERSD is tied to the recipient, not the sender. so not sure who is A or B, but the one signing